# Share global variable to another script python

Tags: python, global-variables, python-2.5

I have two scripts :

1.py

```
activation_splitView = 0
        class MonProg(Frame):
            def __init__(self, master=None):
            blablabla
            def splitDisplay(self):
            blablabla
```

I want to modify the variable `activation_splitView` to 1 when I use the `splitDisplay` function. My second script **2.py** can read `activation_splitDisplay` with the help of import 1 and this code. He read the variable only when he's launch, i dont have to make pipe/multiprocessing and the variable will not use anymore.

```
if 1.activation_splitView == 0:
        tkMessageBox.showwarning('0')
else:
        tkMessageBox.showwarning('1')
```

But I always read 0 for the variable, I don't know how to modify it and send the new value to my second script.

Can you help me please?

Loris

Comment: I dont want to an other script modify the variable, i want to edit in my main script (1.py) the variable, and, when i run the second script he can read the modified value of the the variable, but i can only read the activation_splitView value declared in the scope with the 2.py

Comment: `1` is not a valid object name in Python.  Since a module is an object, then it is not a valid module name either.  Python names should begin with a character in the range A-Z or a-z (underscore implies a special meaning).

Comment: On second reading of your question, are you expecting to share a variable between two *processes*?

Comment: i put 1 and 2 to simplify my explications, in my real code there are A-Z and a-z

Comment: @cdarke yes i want to share this variable from 1.py to 2.py

Comment: OK, now you are opening a huge can of worms.  You have to used shared memory, or maybe you should consider the  `multiprocessing` module in the standard library.  Better yet, consider your design again, is there a better way to communicate?  For example, a named pipe.  Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Synchronisation is an important issue.  You have to consider what each program is doing when one changes the variable.  Does one wait for the other?  What happens if both update the same variable at the same time?  (bad things can happen)

Comment: @cdarke I can already read the variable because i run 2.py after running 1.py, so my problem its only how to modify activation_splitView in 1.py. Because, when i run 2.py the script read 0, which is the default value i set in the scope of 1.py... Im running Windows. Regards

Comment: The variable must be read only when 2.py is launch, i dont use the variable anymore. So i dont have to make pipe or multiprocessing

Comment: Maybe I'm getting the wrong idea.  How are you running 2.py?  Can't you pass the variable value as a command-line argument?

Comment: @cdarke No i cant, 1.py is the main user interface. By default in my main program (1.py) the variable activation_splitView is set to 0 and when the user click on a button i want to modify activation_splitView to 1. The user can also call 2.py from 1.py which is a second interface, and if activation_splitView is to 1 i'll modify geometry/position of the interface on the screen for 2.py

Comment: What mechanism are you using to "call 2.py" from 1.py?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should use, when you use class and return var:

1.py:

```
activation_splitView = 21

class MonProg(object):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # balabala

    def splitDisplay(self):
        global activation_splitView
        # use activation_splitView here.
        # you should save `activation_splitView` to one file, eg: test.ini
```

2.py

```
# in 2.py file.
# read test.ini file in order to `activation_splitView`.
```

Comment: What is MonProg('x')? Why x?
To read activation_splitView in 2.py i have just to make, for exemple, test_var = test.returnValue() ?

Comment: What i have to do in the scope of 2.py? import 1 or what?

Comment: I have changed method, please read code, use test.ini file to save `activation_splitView`.

Comment: Ok i think read a file is the simplest way to do that, thank you so much mate! Regards